# how to edit 2nd editText only if the 1st is edited in recyclerView

Tags: java, android

I'm using editText in recyclerView, I want to display or edit the 2nd one only if  the 1st is filled android java.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution of mine:
In your adapter, create a flag int `currentFilled = -1;`
and update this flag whenever your editText is filled
Like this:

```
        
        EditText edt1 = new EditText(this);
        edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() >0){
                    // this is when your edt1 is filled
//                    edt2.setEnabled(true); // You can enable your edt2 or whatever here
//                    edt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    currentFilled = itemPosition;
                    notifyItemChanged(itemPosition+1) // position you wan to display or edit the edt
                } else {
                    // when edt1 is not filled
                    /// TODO do what ever you want
                }
            }
        });
```

Then in your ViewHolder check if `currentFilled == itemPosition-1`
==>>

```
     edt.setEnabled(true); // You can enable your edt2 or whatever here 
    // or
     edt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

it's may get some issues or not depending on your requirements.
Happy coding :))